# C++: Get name of process executing my application

Tags: shellexecute

My application will be launched by an installer during the installation process, probably using ShellExecute. I would like to get the name of the installer executable when it launches my application.

Can I from my application see a "parent process" somehow? Or can I scan the system for windows with a specific caption and get the name of the .exe owning that window?

This is for MS Windows, and my application is written in C++.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185254/how-can-a-win32-process-get-the-pid-of-its-parent

Answer (score 1):

windows does have the concept of parent process.. i donno why would you just claim that ignorantly..

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ParentPID.aspx

Comment: Wrong. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185254/how-can-a-win32-process-get-the-pid-of-its-parent

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to do that, but I would pass caller name as a parameter to the exe such as
--caller ParentName.  That way you don't even care if it's windows.