# about a process and the process that spawns it (win32/C)

Tags: c, winapi, process

I have an app that will usually be spawned by another app. The UI and behaviour will vary a bit depending on whether the said app was opened directly by the user or spawned. How can I determine if it was launched by the user or spawned?

I have a couple of ideas but they don't seem doable.

1. If there was a way of sending extra app specific param via CreateProcess() this would be simple but I can't find how to do that.
2. If I can find the handle of the parent process, I can determine if it was spawned or not but I can't see how to do that.

Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a Win32 process get the pid of its parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185254/how-can-a-win32-process-get-the-pid-of-its-parent)

Comment: Not a duplicate as there are better solutions to the problem than finding the parent process.

Answer (score 1):

> If there was a way of sending extra
>   app specific param via CreateProcess()

So you have control of the invoking application? If so surely this is what command lines are for?

```
CreateProcess( NULL, "C:\\app.exe /launched_by_app2" ...)
```

Comment: I think you're supposed to repeat the program name as the first command-line parameter in CreateProcess.