# List running jobs in python

Tags: python, linux, shell

How can I get a list of running jobs in python.
ie. I basically want the output of the `jobs` command in a string or list or set.

I am currently trying

```
 p1 = subprocess.Popen(['jobs'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 n = p1.communicate()[0].strip()
```

But this doesnt seem to be working

Comment: In what way is it not working? What output is it giving, vs what output are you getting when you run `jobs` on the command line?

Comment: `subprocess.check_output('jobs', shell=True).split('\n')` would be an shorter version to do what you want.

Comment: The `jobs` command shows jobs managed by the current shell; why would your Popen subshell be managing any jobs?

Comment: Let me rephrase: ``subprocess.check_output('jobs', shell=True).split('\n')` would be a shorter version to **not** do what you want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to keep track of it yourself.  The shell keeps track of all of its subprocess jobs, but you're not a shell, so you have to do the tracking yourself.  `jobs` is a [Bash shell builtin command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Builtins), not an actual executable which is run.  When you do `subprocess.Popen(['jobs'], shell=True)`, you're spawning a new shall and asking *it* for *its* jobs, which is of course empty since it's a new shell without any running jobs.

If you can't keep track of your own running jobs, you're going to have a harder time.  On Linux, you could parse [`/proc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) and look for all processes which have you as a parent.  On Windows, you could do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/558251/9530) using a wrapper such as pywin32 or the `ctypes` module to access the Win32 API.

Comment: If you can't keep track of your own running jobs, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: how about getting ppid and parsing the output of ps for that ppid