# Get Process Parent in Qt

Tags: windows, macos, qt, process

I'm using Qt on Mac and Windows.
Is there a good way with QProcess or something similar to find the parent process of my application?
I need to find out what application launched my application.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any such API.

Comment: QProcess cannot do this. Could you elaborate a little on what you are planning to do with this information. Maybe there is another simple way to do it.

Comment: I just need to know what process started my application and change the way my application reacts accordingly.

Comment: You'll possibly need to write two solutions as the Windows process tree, and Mac process tree are different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185254/how-can-a-win32-process-get-the-pid-of-its-parent shows how to extract the PID of the parent for win32.

Comment: I guess the parent applications are not your own, so interprocess communication or passing arguments is not possible, right?

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus - You are correct.