# How can you ensure an executable is opened via another executable?

Tags: c#, windows

There's a neat little trick that you can use to never have the OS hold a lock on the `.dll`'s / `.exe`'s an `.exe` needs to run.

Let's say our directory looks like this:

```
>opener.exe
>actualProgram.exe
>dependency.dll
```

As a basic example, we could do this:

```
namespace Opener
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
                domain.FriendlyName,
                domain.Evidence,
                domain.BaseDirectory,
                domain.RelativeSearchPath,
                true,  // "shadow copy" files: copy rather than lock
                domain.SetupInformation.AppDomainInitializer,
                domain.SetupInformation.AppDomainInitializerArguments
            );
            string assembly = 
                System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location 
                + "\\..\\actualProgram.exe";
            newDomain.ExecuteAssembly(assembly, args);
        }
    }
}
```

We could also put more logic in there, which we could use to actually replace/update `actualProgram.exe` despite an instance of the process being opened. Try it: you'll be able to delete/modify/replace dependencies and the "actual" program when it's loaded via the "opener". Obviously this has its benefits, namely making updates a lot easier.

But in your "actual.exe", how can you be sure that it was loaded via another executable, and know that it was loaded without having a lock taken on the `.exe`? If someone is to just load the "actual.exe", i.e. not via the "opener", I want to make sure that the process immediately exits.

Hints?

Comment: Interesting approach, not seen it before. I guess if it's not security critical, you can just expect a parameter in the `actualProgram.exe`, which the `opener.exe` will provide. If a user simply clicks on the `actualProgram.exe` it should check if the parameter is present and exit or [insert your action here]. E.g.: `opener => actualProgram calledByOpener` in the `actualProgram` there is an `if(args[0] != "calledByOpener") exit -1;`

Comment: There are protections against *casual* misuse, such as that suggested by oleksii, but you'll not be able to protect yourself from someone determined to force your application to run (for starters, they could disassemble the code, remove the protections, then reassemble).

Comment: If you are just looking to stop someone from launching `actual.exe` from Explorer or cmd, rename it to something like `userdata.dat`, and rename your opener to `actual.exe`.  The name won't prevent the app domain from loading it, but it will prevent Explorer or cmd from opening it.. and it will discourage *most* users from poking at it - if you pick the right name.

Answer (score 2):

1. Pass a command line parameter to `actualProgram.exe` that lets it know it was launched by the launcher. (Also suggested in a comment on the OP by oleksii)
2. Set an environment variable in the launcher that can be inherited by the child process.
3. Use one of the documented methods for getting the parent process id, and use that to get information about the launching process. (Of course if the parent process terminates, Windows is free to re-assign the PID to a new process.)
4. Create a memory-mapped file/named pipe/etc. in the launcher that can be used to pass information to the child.
5. Manually load and unload the library references in the child.  If they are .Net assemblies, you can use the `AssemblyResolve` event, loading the file from disk into a byte array and using the `Assembly.Load(byte[], byte[])` overload.

Note: As long as all of your assemblies are loaded manually or by the runtime before you modify/move/delete them, you're *probably* ok. Also, changing the DLL after it's been loaded will *probably* have no effect on the running process.  I say probably in both cases, because it's generally a good idea to leave the libraries alone at runtime, especially if you aren't loading them manually.

See Also:

- [Run-Time Dynamic Linking @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [How can a Win32 process get the pid of its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185254/how-can-a-win32-process-get-the-pid-of-its-parent)
- [Assembly.Load Method (Byte[], Byte[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twt16z2x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

How about sending a custom message to the application after it is launched?  The code to **launch** would be something like this:

```
private void LaunchApplication()
{
  ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();

  //you could pass in arguments here if you wanted
  start.Arguments = string.Empty;

  //your EXE name
  start.FileName = @"c:\your_program.exe";

  start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
  start.CreateNoWindow = true;

  Process p = Process.Start(start);
  while (0 == (int)p.MainWindowHandle)
  {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
  }
  processHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;
  label1.Text = processHandle.ToString();

  //the launched program will receive this message as a signal that it can continue
  SendNotifyMessage(processHandle, 99999, UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

and the application you are **running** would need a short custom windows message handler to watch out for the "stay-alive" signal.

```
private bool allowedToLive = false;
//how long will we wait for the signal?  should arrive in < 1 second
private int TimeoutSeconds = 1;
private DateTime appStartTime = DateTime.Now;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  base.WndProc(ref m);
  //receiving the special message means we are allowed to live.
  if(!allowedToLive)
  {
    allowedToLive = (m.Msg == 99999);
    if (!allowedToLive && (TimeoutSeconds <= DateTime.Now.Subtract(appStartTime).Seconds))
    {
      //times up.  quit.
      Application.Exit();
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't want to rely on the timing of windows messages, you could alter your target program to launch, but not actually begin doing anything until it receives the custom message.