# How do I print to the console while an SDL 2 program is running?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, sdl-2

I'd like to print some debugging stuff to the console while running my SDL 2 program, but it seems impossible. `printf("Hi!\n")` and `SDL_Log("Hi!\n")` both won't do me any good.

I even tried printing before initializing SDL (and after quitting it, too), but to no avail. It seems like merely *importing* the SDL library makes it impossible to print anything to the console.

Here are the parameters I'm compiling with, since it's possible that might have something to do with it:

```
g++ hello.cc -IC:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2 -LC:\mingw_dev_lib\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -std=c++11
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably caused by sdl2main library. Normally it's not actually needed in normal sdl program, but it causes problems with debug output missing...

Comment: @tp1 Were you suggesting that I delete sdl2main? The closest thing I found to that was `libSDL2main.a`, and deleting that file caused even more issues.

Comment: This could be something you're doing in SDL or a platform-related issue. I'm using SDL2 right now and have no issues printing via cout immediately during runtime. I'm also using MSYS2 on Windows.

Comment: This is not very definitive but might be helpful: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/299349-cout-to-console-in-sdl/

Comment: I figured it out from some other site, so I'll go ahead and answer my own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I figured out what's preventing me from seeing output. These compile options

`-Wl,-subsystem,windows`

essentially disable the console window, preventing output from being displayed. This is good for when a game is finished, but terrible for debugging. So, I went ahead and removed those compile options and now `printf()` and `SDL_Log()` work perfectly fine.

Comment: If any one is using pkg-config you will have to save the output and remove  -mwindows

Comment: Thank you! This behavior has been ruining my week

Answer (score 6):

Since this is still on going issue with SDL2 in window when using mingw, here is the better solution that I found and tested as working.

Do not remove the **-mwindows** build option as others have suggested. You should be adding **`pkg-config --libs SDL2`** as your build options but for the debug build options you should also add **-mconsole** at the end. It should come after the **-mwindows** flag.

Debug: **`pkg-config --libs SDL2` -mconsole**
Release: **`pkg-config --libs SDL2`**

*Note*: I'm compiling for Windows 10, SDL2 v2.0.9, Msys64, mingw64, Code::Blocks 17.12
**`pkg-config --libs SDL2`** expands to:
**-LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows**

References:
[SDL2: keep the -mwindows flag in the pkg-config --libs output #2419](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/pull/2419)
[configure: force -mconsole when linking SDL under MinGW](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=c5308eea29216c218b61599dc83911d2c1afe716)

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach for debugging console:

```
static ULONG_PTR GetParentProcessId() // By Napalm @ NetCore2K
{
    ULONG_PTR pbi[6];
    ULONG ulSize = 0;
    LONG (WINAPI *NtQueryInformationProcess)(HANDLE ProcessHandle, ULONG ProcessInformationClass,
            PVOID ProcessInformation, ULONG ProcessInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength); 
    *(FARPROC *)&NtQueryInformationProcess = 
        GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("NTDLL.DLL"), "NtQueryInformationProcess");
    if(NtQueryInformationProcess){
        if(NtQueryInformationProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0,
                    &pbi, sizeof(pbi), &ulSize) >= 0 && ulSize == sizeof(pbi))
            return pbi[5];
    }
    return (ULONG_PTR)-1;
}

static void _windows_init_console(int argc, char **argv) {
    (void)argc, (void)argv;
    ULONG_PTR ppid = GetParentProcessId();
    if(ppid == (ULONG_PTR)-1) {
        AllocConsole();
    } else {
        AttachConsole(ppid);
    }

    freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin); 
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout); 
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr); 
}
```

(`GetParentProcessId` comes from [How can a Win32 process get the pid of its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185254/how-can-a-win32-process-get-the-pid-of-its-parent/3137081#3137081)). Works quite fine, but I still cannot make it work with `grep`/`findstr` etc. (i.e. 'true' stdout with pipe redirection).

Answer (score 0):

Since SDL2 use the windows subsystem, you can open the console window by using Win32 API.

According to this [blog post](https://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/console-window-win32-app/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // SDL2 init code...

    // Just before the event loop
    AllocConsole();

    HANDLE handle_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long) handle_out, _O_TEXT);
    FILE* hf_out = _fdopen(hCrt, "w");
    setvbuf(hf_out, NULL, _IONBF, 1);
    *stdout = *hf_out;

    HANDLE handle_in = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long) handle_in, _O_TEXT);
    FILE* hf_in = _fdopen(hCrt, "r");
    setvbuf(hf_in, NULL, _IONBF, 128);
    *stdin = *hf_in;

    // use the console just like a normal one - printf(), getchar(), ...
}
```

Hope this helps.