# It is necessary to obtain parent process_id and username about the process in php

Tags: php, winforms, winapi, process

It is necessary to obtain information about the process in php (php + IIS + WinServer 2012):

- **process_id** - pid
- **parent process_id** - ppid
- **username** - username, whose name was launched the process displayed in the Task Manager in the "user"

I use two approaches

```
exec('C:\Windows\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "pid eq 99999" /FI "USERNAME eq MYUSERNAME"', $output);
```

If such a process is, it appears, but I can not get parent_process_id :(

If I use:

```
exec('C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmic.exe process where 'parentprocessid=\"$ppid\"' get parentprocessid,processid"', $output);
```

I can not get username :(

Someone faced with a challenge or know how to get this information?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can help. http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getppid.php

Comment: *Parent process ID* is useless information on Windows. It does get recorded, when a process is created, but it isn't being used for anything. A 'parent' process can terminate, while its children continue to run. At that point the process ID entry won't get updated, and now points to a non-existent process, or worse, to another process altogether, because process IDs do get reused. Have a look at this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/185254/1889329).

Answer (score 0):

You can run both and group the results by process_id. Iterate both the result sets and find the process_id matches.