# How to know how my exe run?

Tags: cmd, vb6, exe

There is 2 ways that I can run exe file: with double click or via command line.
I want to do different function from each way..

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a command line when running from the command line, e.g. use command$ to detect yourapp.exe -c

Comment: Get parent process handle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185254/how-can-a-win32-process-get-the-pid-of-its-parent and examine whether it was launched from cmd.exe or explore.exe.

Comment: question unclear, not specific.    More details plz.

Answer (score 1):

You could also start via a Process, Schedule, register an extension, Autostart any many more. You need to tell us what you want to achieve for a satisfying answer. Following Answer is for switch a command-line and a gui mode.

If you have the Install of you Program in you hands, you can simply use "Command" to read the commandline arguments and use that for a command line mode and a gui mode.
Make a switch like "-gui" and simply write

```
If Command = "-gui" Then
    frmMain.Show
End If
```