# query/find launching process windows

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system

6 up votes for a comment telling me its a duplicate when it is not.
4 votes to close despite no one reading the actual question.
no answer accepted.

I have found a link that explains.

https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.d05jjnucn

So long SO, account closed.

Comment: Its not a duplicate. I don't need the pid and I don't care if it is recycled. I only want the image name.

Comment: Ok. So use the technique described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185254/how-can-a-win32-process-get-the-pid-of-its-parent to get the parent process PID. Then call OpenProcess() to get the process handle and QueryFullProcessImageName() on the handle to get the image filename.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know processA name,

you could use [EnumProcesses()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms682629(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the list of all processes,

then [GetModuleBaseName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms683196(v=vs.85).aspx) to check the name of each process (you will need to open them with [OpenProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx) before that)

and when you find the right one : [QueryFullProcessImageName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx) with the Id given by EnumProcesses()

Comment: "Assuming you know processA name." I dont know the name of process A.

Comment: from this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms684868(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: my bad, send the last comment by error. this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms684868(v=vs.85).aspx        says "A process can use the Process32First function to obtain the process identifier of its parent process". Maybe it is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use the technique from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3137081/6172310 to obtain the Process ID (pid) of the parent process.

Call `OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, false, pid)` to get a handle to the process (don't forget to close the handle when you are done!)

Call `QueryFullProcessImageName(processHandle, 0, outputString, sizeof(outputString))` to get the image name.

Comment: Your trying to fit this solution to my requirement which is not what I am asking. I will edit the question to be more clear.